# view and data API about use、upload、pricing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

1. view and data API有中国区联系人吗
2. 如果想长期显示模型可以存储到自己服务器吗
3. 对于中国区域是否有费用
4. 加载的css、js是否有国内CDN
5. 对一些后缀.SLDASM解析不好，怎么解决

Comment: Stack Overflow is English-only. Please translate your post into the correct language.

Comment: 不知Stackoverflow为何不接受我输入的一些内容，正在检查...This is a Chinese customer who is using Autodesk Forge. I have replied the questions, and suggested this customer to post question in English in the future

Comment: 看来是不接受中文，我用英文解答了，您可以添加我的微信thiscoldwood，我和您做说明。

Comment: thank everybody very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

（This is a Chinese customer who is using Autodesk Forge. I have replied the questions, and suggested this customer to post question in English in the future）

Because I cannot type Chinese here, I have to answer you in English. Please find the contact ways

1. I am in charge of Forge in China. In this link you can find [Forge Support](https://devtechchina.github.io/ForgeHelp/) where you can add my **WeChat**. In addition, the term 'Viewer and Data' is not used anymore. Now the technologies behind the 'Viewer and Data' are composed by several Forge APIs: Data Management, Model Derivatives, Forge Viewer.
2. yes, you can download the translated package of SVF (format for browser) and deploy the data package to you server. Please check [this site](http://extract.autodesk.io/).
3. It is free to the regions out of U.S.and E.U. at this moment. So you can use Forge services for free at this moment.
4. No, as far as I know, there is not CDN in China for Forge.
5. Please log a new case and provide necessary model that can reproduce this problem you hit. And also highlight which section you think a problem. Then we can diagnose what happened with the translating.

Finally, as you can see, Stackoverflow (SO) mainly supports English, though you could type in Chinese. One of the reasons why we directed the customers to log case in SO is because global web developers & Forge peers might be able to offer a hand to your question. community helps community. So please try best to log case in English here. It does not require a professional English. Some simple description that can tell what your problem is is enough. And the moderators could also help you to polish your description.  Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: what is your wechat number,my wechat number is 'myname9c',thanks